# How to get response from webview after send the request to client

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I am new here. I am facing this issue last 3 days. we have Web application and Android application.

In Web application we receive requests (POST method) from clients and redirect to a success or failure URL depending on the outcome.

Now problem with Android application: Using Webview I am sending same request to server. my code is executing but I don't know few things.

1. what will be the success and failure URL for Android?
2. how to get response from client side and get back to the activity?

by default I give success URL is Google.com and failure URL is Gmail.com. If I give my Web application success and failure URL it will give response in server side.

**Note:** In this code JavaScript code there I don't know how to use. I refer somewhere else. `PayUJavaScriptInterface`, `success()`, and `popup()` method not using. If I have to use for getting response then tell me how to use.

Here is my code for my activity

```
 public class PayMentGateWay extends Activity {
 private ArrayList<String> post_val = new ArrayList<String>();
 private String post_Data="";
 WebView webView ;
 final Activity activity = this;
 private String tag = "PayMentGateWay";
 private String hash,hashSequence;
 String merchant_key="JBZaLc";
    String salt="GQs7yium";
    String action1 ="";
    String base_url="https://test.payu.in";
    int error=0;
    String hashString="";
    Map<String,String> params;
    String txnid ="";

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();


@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
     getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);

    post_val.add("key");
    post_val.add("JBZaLc");
    post_val.add("txnid");
    post_val.add("5d59dae66618a14f5020");
    post_val.add("amount");
    post_val.add("100.00");
    post_val.add("productinfo");

    post_val.add("{paymentParts:[{name:abc,description:abcd,value:500,isRequired:true,settlementEvent:EmailConfirmation}], paymentIdentifiers:[{field:CompletionDate, value:25/06/2015}]}");
    post_val.add("firstname");
    post_val.add("pqrs");
    post_val.add("email");
    post_val.add("xxxx@xxxmail.com");
    post_val.add("phone");
    post_val.add("xxxxxxxxxx");
    post_val.add("surl");
    post_val.add("https://www.google.com");
    post_val.add("furl");
    post_val.add("https://www.gmail.com");
    post_val.add("hash");
    post_val.add("");
    post_val.add("provider");
    post_val.add("payu_paisa");
    Log.d(tag, "post_val: "+post_val);
    params= new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i = 0;i<post_val.size();){
        params.put(post_val.get(i), post_val.get(i+1));

        i+=2;   
    }

    if(empty(params.get("txnid"))){
        Random rand = new Random();
        String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())+(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        txnid=hashCal("SHA-256",rndm).substring(0,20);
        popup("txnid : " + txnid);
        System.out.println("......txnid...... " + txnid);
    } else {
        txnid=params.get("txnid");
        System.out.println("....else.......txnid...... " + txnid);
    }

        //String udf2 = txnid;
    String txn="abcd";
     hash="";
    String hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
    if(empty(params.get("hash")) && params.size()>0) {
        if( empty(params.get("key"))
            || empty(params.get("txnid"))
            || empty(params.get("amount"))
            || empty(params.get("firstname"))
            || empty(params.get("email"))
            || empty(params.get("phone"))
            || empty(params.get("productinfo"))
            || empty(params.get("surl"))
            || empty(params.get("furl"))
            || empty(params.get("service_provider"))

    ) {
            String[] hashVarSeq = hashSequence.split("\\|");
            for (int i = 0; i < hashVarSeq.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("<<<<<>>>>>>>> " + hashVarSeq[i]);
            }

            for(String part : hashVarSeq)
            {
                hashString= (empty(params.get(part))) ? hashString.concat("") : hashString.concat(params.get(part));
                hashString=hashString.concat("|");
                System.out.println("??????? " + hashString);
            }
            hashString=hashString.concat(salt);


             hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
             System.out.println(hashString + " /////~~~~~~ " + hash);
            action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
        }
    }
    else if(!empty(params.get("hash")))
    {
        hash=params.get("hash");
        action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!HASHHHHHHH!!!!!! " + hash);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onReceivedError>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onReceivedSslError>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "SslError! " +  error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>shouldOverrideUrlLoading>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>onPageFinished>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        }


    });


    webView.setVisibility(0);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(activity), "PayUMoney");
    Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapParams.put("key",merchant_key);
    mapParams.put("hash",PayMentGateWay.this.hash);
    mapParams.put("txnid",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
    Log.d(tag, "txnid: "+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
    mapParams.put("service_provider","payu_paisa");

        mapParams.put("amount",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"));
        mapParams.put("firstname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"));
        mapParams.put("email",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"));
        mapParams.put("phone",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"));

        mapParams.put("productinfo",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"));
        mapParams.put("surl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"));
        mapParams.put("furl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"));
        mapParams.put("lastname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"));

        mapParams.put("address1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"));
        mapParams.put("address2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"));
        mapParams.put("city",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"));
        mapParams.put("state",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"));

        mapParams.put("country",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"));
        mapParams.put("zipcode",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"));
        mapParams.put("udf1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"));
        mapParams.put("udf2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"));

        mapParams.put("udf3",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"));
        mapParams.put("udf4",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"));
        mapParams.put("udf5",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"));
        mapParams.put("pg",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"));
        webview_ClientPost(webView, action1, mapParams.entrySet());

}
public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

    mHandler = null;

    Intent intent = new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this, MainActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("result", "success");

    intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);

    startActivity(intent);

    finish();

    }

    });

    }

}
 public void webview_ClientPost(WebView webView, String url, Collection< Map.Entry<String, String>> postData){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<html><head></head>");
        sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
        sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
            sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        }
        sb.append("</form></body></html>");
        Log.d(tag, "webview_ClientPost called");
       webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
 }


 public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {

 mHandler = null;

 Intent intent = new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this, MainActivity.class);

 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

 intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME, "success");

 intent.putExtra(Constants._ID, paymentId);

 startActivity(intent);

 finish();

 }

 });

 }


public boolean empty(String s)
{
    if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String hashCal(String type,String str){
    byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try{
    MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
    algorithm.reset();
    algorithm.update(hashseq);
    byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



    for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
        String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
        if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
        hexString.append(hex);
    }

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

    return hexString.toString();


}

public void popup(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(PayMentGateWay.this, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: You do mean sending a request to the server don't you? Your webview_ClientPost isn't making a post. loadUrl only results in a get. If you explained your question better someone might be able to give you a few more leads.

Comment: @e4c5  hi... sending a request to the server of client side.its working fine i finish all process .but after everything done in client side.how to come back in android app with response. and what will be sucess and failure url for my app.

Comment: Your code in it's current form is unreadable but a few dubious areas: you don't really want to call onCreate from javascript. As already mentioned webview.loadurl() is only GET and not post and your mapParams is just going waste.

Comment: @e4c5  thanks for edit and correct my Qn.

Comment: @Inzimam Tariq IT thanks for edit. Since  submit the post 1 day over .still waiting for solution .

Comment: In the 1st line you wrote "We have `web` application & `android` application. is in android you have web app or web app is separate ??

Comment: @Inzimam: please stop formatting non-code as code. Language/library/framework/product names are NOT code. Only code is code.

Comment: @Inzimam Tariq IT  we create a common project as called Standard API for web application and android application .both web and android app called same API to getting the result. Both web and android are separate  but have some common method in API.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should pass your own success and failure url.(Both the url can be same). e.g: www.yourwebsitename.com/payuresponse.php
2. You can handle success or failure by getting the post parameter send by payu ($_POST['status']) to your success or failure url i.e payuresponse.php
3. Add below code as javascript code in bottom of the payuresponse.php

   function success() {

   ```
        Android.success(id,paymentId);

       /*u can pass more parameter too.
        Note : the number of parameter you pass from here should be      
               same you will recieve in PayMentGateWay.java class in   
               your android application*/
      }
      success();
   ```

   You can also do anything you want in your payuresponse.php
4. Just add anotation in your android code

@JavascriptInterface

public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

/*
             u can recieve more parameter too.
             Note : the number of parameter you recieve here should be
                    same you send from payuresponse.php
*/

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

mHandler = null;

Intent intent = new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this, MainActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

intent.putExtra("result", "success");

intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);

startActivity(intent);

finish();

}

});

}
```

5. Hope this will work for you. Enjoy!

Comment: @ shahid   i don't understand your Ans. see my mobile application in java and  pure native app. how can i give "www.yourwebsitename.com/payuresponse.php" url. assume i will give my api method url .it will response me at server side.so how to get the response in android app. i understand what u try to say but how can i call function handleResponse() in PayMentGateWay activity . i know that i don't understand your ans properly but can you guide me .

Comment: Your api method url (success and failure url) should be on live server not on localhost so payu can hit his response on your api method url. The inner class PayUJavaScriptInterface consisiting the function success(long id, final String paymentId) will help you to get response from your api method url. Note that your api method url must consist (<script>function success() {
     Android.success(id,paymentId);
   }
   success();</script>) this javascript function.